# Rails POST and open in popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a form with two different submit buttons. One of them is "preview", the other one is submit.

The desired behavior is :

When clicking the "send" button, the form will be POSTed as normal, and the browser will load the next page returned by the controller.

When clicking the "Preview" button, the form is posted but it will not close the the current page, and instead open the page returned by the controller in a popup or tab (The form remain filled and it's possible to click the send button if the user is satisfied with the preview)

An other possible solution for the preview button, would be to alter the  button to have it send the form via AJAX instead of normal POST, and then I can have a special .js view where I can execute custom code.

So, how would you do it ? I feel like there is probably already an answer, so maybe the phrasing of my question is bad and you can tag it as duplicate ?

```
<%= form_tag ... %>
  ...
  <%= render 'shared/form_submit', text: 'Preview', html_class: 'btn btn-default' %>
  <%= render 'shared/form_submit', text: 'Send', confirmation: @html_warning %>
<% end %>
```